# check boxes not working in IE8 (JQuery)

Tags: jquery, html, css, checkbox, internet-explorer-8

I have gone through questions similar to this on stackoverflow but can't seem to find solution what I was looking for, so I am posting my question.
I have got 2 check boxes (in terms & conditions page) and until  unless the user checks (agrees) both the check boxes, the `continue` button won't get enabled! This is working fine in chrome and IE 9 and later versions.

But this is a **PROBLEM** in IE8, the problem is :
1) User is **ABLE** to check the boxes but the `continue` button is not working!
2) And when the cursor is hovered on `continue` button, it is changing to text input cursor! This is all weird.

Below is my html for check boxes.

```
<label for="f_agree2" class="approval"><input type="checkbox" id="f_agree2" value="1" onclick="checkedFunc('f_agree', 'f_agree2')" name="@parqForm("safety").name" /> I have read the above information making me aware of my requirements to:

<label for="f_agree" class="approval"><input type="checkbox" id="f_agree" value="1" onclick="checkedFunc('f_agree', 'f_agree2')" name="@parqForm("parq").name" /> I have read, understood and completed the PAR-Q, answering NO to all of the questions.</label>
```

Below is  my jquery:

```
function checkedFunc(element1Id, element2Id) {

var myLayer = document.getElementById('acceptbtn');
var element1 = document.getElementById(element1Id);
var element2 = document.getElementById(element2Id);

if (element1.checked === true && element2.checked === true) {
    myLayer.class = "submit"; // displaying error in here
    myLayer.removeAttribute("disabled"); 
} else {
    myLayer.class = "button:disabled";
    myLayer.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
};
}
```

Following is the error:

```
Object expected
Code: 0
URL : //Url of the page
```

**update**

`Continue` button html:

```
<div class="options">
    <button type="submit" disabled="disabled" id="acceptbtn"   class="parqSubmit-grey">Continue</button>
</div>
```

CSS for `button:disabled`

```
input.submit:disabled, button.submit:disabled, input.button:disabled, button:disabled, a.button:disabled {
background: #A5A5A5;
color: #D5D5D5;
text-shadow: none;
border-color: #888;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if IE8 doesn't allow `:` in class names.

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: Shouldn't `.class` be `.className`?

Comment: @Barmar Error is happening in two checkbox html codes and in `myLayer.class = "submit";`

Comment: What is the value of `myLayer` when the error happens?

Comment: @BARMAR I have now changed to  `.className` instead of `.class` and it is Working now BUT before checking the boxes, my continue button should be grayed out, but It is not graying out!

Comment: Please post the HTML and CSS of the continue button.

Comment: That error has gone now! but I think, now it is the issue with `:` . How do I modify that to get it work in IE8?

Comment: Use a class like `button-disabled`. `:` is special in CSS, it's used to for pseudo-selectors, and you shouldn't use it in the actual class name.

Comment: Why do you need to put `disabled` in the class name in the first place? Why don't you just use the `:disabled` modifier in the CSS on an ordinary class?

Comment: I have tried changing it to `button-disabled` , but its not working and I have updated the question with `continue` button html and css. Please have a look

Comment: Do you understand that in the CSS, `input.submit:disabled` doesn't match the class `submit:disabled`. It matches the class `submit`, with the `disabled=disabled` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (element1.checked === true && element2.checked === true) {
    myLayer.className = "submit";
    myLayer.removeAttribute("disabled"); 
} else {
    myLayer.className = "parqsubmit-Grey";
    myLayer.setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
};
```

`:disabled` isn't part of the class name, it's a CSS selector for elements that have the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: Yes I understood now! Yes I have changed it to parqsubmit-grey and updated my css. Thank you so much!